# A bootstrap column that should stretch 100% of width is not doing so, only in Angular

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I have a page with a side navigation bar and a content area.
Here is a simplified representation of what it looks like:

[image]

```
[https://jsfiddle.net/hd46twu1/6/][2]
```

I'm rewriting the same application using Angular and I'm having a bad time trying to make the content area to stretch to the whole available width.
Here is what is happening:

[image]

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-89rbp4

How can I make the column to stretch in Angular just as it does on the application without Angular?

Comment: Do you have a viewport meta-tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the main in div with a width of 100% or apply the class directly on main directive

```
// app.component.css    
    .full-width {
      width:100%
    }
```

in the html :

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <app-navbar></app-navbar>
  <div class="full-width" >
  <app-main></app-main>
  </div>
</div>
```

A stackblitz example : 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kya7fk?file=src/app/main/main.component.html

PS: you can also apply, `height: 100%` to stretch it vertically, see updated stackblitz :)